# Gulp Yaml Front Matter to JSON add File Name

Tags: json, yaml, markdown, gulp

I'm not sure what is the best way to go about this.

I would like to get the `yaml` `front matter` from a markdown file convert it to `json` while adding the name of the file and then combine them in a single `array` `json` file.

E.g. the files `bananas.md` and `apples.md`,

```
---
title: Bananas
type: yellow
count:
  - 1
  - 2
---

# My Markdown File
```

`apples.md`:

```
---
title: Apples
type: red
count:
  - 3
  - 4
---

# My Markdown File 2
```

converts to `all.json`:

```
[{"title":"Bananas","type":"yellow","count":[1,2],"file":"bananas"},
{"title":"Apples","type":"red","count":[3,4],"file":"apples"}]
```

Of course, there wouldn't be a return as it would be compact.

I've found some `gulp` plugins but it doesn't seem any of them do exactly what I need, even combined, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**, I created the plugin `gulp-pluck` which vastly simplifies the process.

Here's how it works:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var data = require('gulp-data');
var pluck = require('gulp-pluck');
var frontMatter = require('gulp-front-matter');

gulp.task('front-matter-to-json', function(){
  return gulp.src('./posts/*.md')
  .pipe(frontMatter({property: 'meta'}))
  .pipe(data(function(file){
    file.meta.path = file.path;
  }))
  .pipe(pluck('meta', 'posts-metadata.json'))
  .pipe(data(function(file){
    file.contents = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(file.meta))
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

**End Update**

---

OK, took the time to figure this out. `Gulp` needs a built-in `reduce` function! (Maybe I'll work on that some time.)

Dependencies include: `gulp`, `gulp-front-matter`, `gulp-filter`, `event-stream`, `stream-reduce`, and `gulp-rename`.

Written in **[LiveScript](http://livescript.net/)**:

```
gulp.task 'concatYaml' ->
   devDest = './dev/public/'
   gulp.src './src/posts/*.md'
      .pipe filter posted
      .pipe front-matter {property: 'meta'}
      .pipe es.map (file, cb) ->
         file.meta.name = path.basename file.path
         file.meta.url = toUrlPath file.meta.name
         cb null, file
      .pipe reduce ((acc, file) -> 
         | acc =>
            acc.meta.push file.meta
            acc
         | _ =>
            acc = file
            acc.meta = [file.meta]
            acc
      ), void
      .pipe es.map (file, cb) ->
         file.contents = new Buffer JSON.stringify file.meta
         cb null, file
      .pipe rename 'posts.json'
      .pipe gulp.dest devDest
```

And the **JavaScript** equivalent:

```
gulp.task('concatYaml', function(){
  var devDest;
  devDest = './dev/public/';
  return gulp.src('./src/posts/*.md')
  .pipe(filter(posted))
  .pipe(frontMatter({ property: 'meta' }))
  .pipe(es.map(function(file, cb){
    file.meta.name = path.basename(file.path);
    file.meta.url = toUrlPath(file.meta.name);
    return cb(null, file);
  }))
  .pipe(reduce(function(acc, file){
    switch (false) {
    case !acc:
      acc.meta.push(file.meta);
      return acc;
    default:
      acc = file;
      acc.meta = [file.meta];
      return acc;
    }
  }, void 8))
  .pipe(es.map(function(file, cb){
    file.contents = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(file.meta));
    return cb(null, file);
  }))
  .pipe(rename('posts.json'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(devDest));
});
```